# How to embed jQuery/javascript in JSF XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, richfaces

I'd like to focus on the first `h:inputSecret` component in my RichFaces `rich:modalPanel`.  I've read I need to use the javascript I've included in the list below but it simply doesn't work (Win FF).  Can anyone tell me why not?  I've tried autofocussing on id="Form" and giving the panelGrid an id and using that to no avail. Any help appreciated.

```
                    <rich:modalPanel id="PwdPanel" autosized="true" width="300" onshow="autofocus('FormNewP0')">
                    <a4j:region id="FormCont">
                        <a4j:form name="Form">
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="padding: 2px;">
                                <h:outputText value="New password&#160;" />
                                <h:inputSecret id="FormNewP0"
                                    value="#{MyBacking.dbNewPwd0}" />

                                <h:outputText value="Re-enter new password&#160;" />
                                <h:inputSecret id="FormNewP1"
                                    value="#{MyBacking.dbNewPwd1}" />

                                <h:outputText value="" />
                                <h:panelGroup>
                                    <a4j:commandButton value="Submit"
                                        action="#{MyBacking.dbPwdChange}"
                                        oncomplete="#{MyBacking.dbPwdError == true ? 'Richfaces.showModalPanel(\'ErrorPanel\');' : 'Richfaces.hideModalPanel(\'ErrorPanel\');Richfaces.hideModalPanel(\'PwdPanel\');'}"
                                        reRender="FormCont,FormText" />
                                    <h:outputText value="&#160;" />
                                    <a4j:commandButton value="Cancel"
                                        onclick="#{rich:component('PwdPanel')}.hide();return false;" />
                                </h:panelGroup>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </a4j:form>
                    </a4j:region>
                </rich:modalPanel>
                <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
                    function autofocus(containerId) {
                      var element = jQuery(":input:not(:button):visible:enabled:first", '#'+containerId);
                      if (element != null) {
                        element.focus().select();
                      }
                    }
                </script>
```

Comment: The server side source code is irrelevant in the story as JavaScript doesn't see any line of it. The client side source code is more of interest since that's the only which JavaScript can see and access. Rightclick page in webbrowser and choose *View Source*. By the way, your downvote on my other answer on a question describing the same symptoms as yours is imho a bit silly since you don't have the **same problem**.

Comment: hmm, i'm working on several similar problems actually so it may have been the same.  or it might have been a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try

```
jQuery("##{rich:clientId('FormNewP0')").focus().select();
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the jQuery library on your page. Try using the below make sure the jQuery is included,

<a4j:loadScript src="resource://jquery.js"/>

Refer to the below site for details,

http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_jQuery.html